# Why close my question here?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

I was asking if there's VMware API that allow you to run a program inside Windows Virtual Machines, instead of copying and double-click executing, just like VirtualBox SDK.

[The link to the question is here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110669/executing-a-program-in-vmware-machines-not-inside-the-machine)

Comment: Have you tried any yet? Or is this the first time you've looked?

Comment: Correct. It should be reclosed as "not a real question"

Comment: FWIW the original question was *on-topic*, and I shouldn't have closed it as such.  However, the original version was *very much* "Not A Real Question" and it should have been closed as *that*.  Apologies for any confusion this might have caused.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your question is:

> #### Executing a program in VMware machines, not inside the machine
>
> I have multiple VMware machines, they're all running Windows server, and I would like to run a program in all these machines, not by copying + double-click executing, but use some VMware API to do that, just like VirtualBox SDK.

What's missing in there is... a question! I read it twice to understand what your question actually is and that's not good. I went through your latest questions, and I did notice a couple more where the core question isn't immediately obvious. For starters, please make the core question blatantly obvious, something like:

> Is there a VMware API that allow you to run a program inside Windows Virtual Machines, instead of copying and double-click executing, just like VirtualBox SDK?

Now that we've clarified what the question is, the next step is to see if it's on topic or not. Well, I'd say it's borderline, VMware is a software tool commonly used by programmers and you seem to be looking for a programming solution, however there is no evident effort to solve your own problem. Did you research [VMware's APIs](http://www.vmware.com/support/pubs/sdk_pubs.html)? "Is there an API" is *not* a question fit for Stack Overflow, we are not a replacement for a search engine.

In short, while my interpretation question may be on topic, I'd flag it as "not a real question". Please always do some research of your own before asking on Stack Overflow, and take care to make at least the core question blatantly obvious.

---

**Update**

The question was [edited, and re-opened by the community](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12110669/revisions), and you got a great answer. That's all good, but please don't assume that it's ok to not do any research of your own in the future.

Comment: Post-update update: the question has been re-closed.  It seems that this question contains a wedge issue ...

Comment: @dbaseman imho the question should stay closed, there's no evident effort in it, and I really don't want SO to be a place where answers just copy paste the manual. kiamlaluno took care to write a good answer, but in reality the answer to all "is there an API/function" questions is either a link to the documentation or a simple "no there isn't".

Answer (score 6):

The close reason is right there at the bottom of the question.

> closed as off topic by casperOne♦ 21 hours ago
>
> Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to relate to programming or software development within the scope defined in the FAQ. Consider editing the question or leaving comments for improvement if you believe the question can be reworded to fit within the scope. Read more about closed questions here.

If your question is about programming, you need to edit it to make that clear.  Right now it appears that it is not.

Comment: I find this explanation unsatisfying. I initially thought like this as well but when re-reading the question I saw that it was about the VMware API, not about the GUI interfaces.

Comment: Strange answer, the term "API" is unclear at SO?

Comment: Throwing around terms void of a question still isn't a question. SDK pointers into garbage collection JSON. What's happening with the API? What are they trying to do with that API? @uph

Comment: @UphillLuge What he's trying to do with the API is unclear.